# unable to save new jsx file using extendscript toolkit

Tags: debugging, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am using MAC OS, In Adobe InDesignCC2019 (`Window/Utilities/Scripts/`),  creating new `jsx` script in `ExtendScript` and trying to save a the `.jsx` file but I am getting the error `can't write the file I/O error`. I have attached the error screen shot for reference.

I am trying to save the my new `jsx` file in the same place where other `jsx` file located i.e., `samples` folder

[image]

Comment: Check whether you have `Read & Write` permission enabled for the `samples` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var mainFolder = new Folder ("~/Desktop/main");
```